# Appending/Inserting 10 out of 1000 data every 5 minute to MongoDB using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, csv

I am currently trying to insert ***10 new data every 5 minute***, out of the *1000 data* that i currently have on my csv file.

How can i do so? Help would be appreciated

The following is my code for `appendMongo.js`

```js
var fs= require('fs');
var csv = require('fast-csv');

var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/insertDB';
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;


var data;

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
    } else {
      console.log('Connection established to', url);
      var collection = db.collection('airports');
      readData=fs.createReadStream('1000data.csv').pipe(csv())
                   .on('data',function(data){
                      collection.insert({'data': data});
                   })
                   .on('end',function(data){
                      console.log('Read finished');
                   })

    }
  }); //End of Mongo connect
```

Everything for the csv file is similar, as i just copy and paste the documents as i am required to do 1000 data that i am asked to do so.

This is part of the data out of 1000 data for `1000data.csv`

```html
Machine Unit,Air Temperature °C,Water Temperature °C,Heat Temperature °C,Room Temperature °C,Date,Time
1,61,54,87,20,12/3/2016,8:39AM
2,41,57,92,21,29/9/2016,3:51PM
3,39,53,89,22,22/12/2016,5:30PM
4,56,27,87,23,9/7/2016,6:54AM
5,71,85,76,24,21/10/2016,7:29PM
6,82,64,85,25,22/3/2016,9:38PM
7,91,73,94,26,21/10/2016,1:30PM
8,35,79,89,27,30/4/2016,2:17PM
9,29,59,83,28,18/7/2016,7:49AM
10,19,61,80,29,27/9/2016,8:21PM
```

Comment: Have you tried using 'setTimeout'? You can keep a count and increase it with 10 in every 5 minutes once insert is done.

Comment: How can i do so? I am currently new to nodejs. Can you kindly teach me how by providing a code? @Shrabanee

Comment: Can you show us what your `data` looks like?

Comment: Hi @Shrabanee, i have edited the post. Can you kindly take a look. I appreciate your help sincerely, thank you so much

Comment: Inside `.on('data',function(data)` what is the type of `data` you are getting? Is it an array?

Comment: Yes, the data i am getting is an array. I have successfully appended the 1000 data into MongoDB. However, my new task now is to append 10 data out of 1000 data every 5 minute into MongoDB.

Comment: @Shrabanee sorry i forgotten to mention you, i am new to this website and the whole programming thing. My apologies, hope you can kindly help me as this is for my project

Comment: Take a look into [setInterval](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_args)

Answer (score 1):

Just keep adding data to an array and have a seperate function to execute every 5mins. This function then can handle the mongodb connection work.

Barebones below

```
'use strict';
var fs= require('fs');
var csv = require('fast-csv');
var dataArray = [];
var finishedReading = false;
//set interval limit as you like 
var interval = 1000 * 10; //10secs
fs.createReadStream('data.csv').pipe(csv())
                   .on('data',function(data){
                      console.log(data);
                      dataArray.push(data)
                   })
                   .on('end',function(data){
                      console.log('Read finished');
                      finishedReading = true;
                   })


var intervalFn = setInterval(function(){
   //you can have check for 10 since you want that many items
    if(dataArray.length >= 2){
        var twoItems = dataArray.splice(0,2);
        console.log(new Date() + twoItems);
        //execute mongodb code from here
    }else if(finishedReading){
        //clean up if items left in array are less than 10 and also clear this interval function
        console.log(new Date() + dataArray.length);
        clearInterval(intervalFn);
    }
},interval)
```

Here is the output of interval function to show that array is processed after every 10secs

```
Wed Dec 28 2016 14:46:09 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)Machine Unit,Air Temperature �C,Water Temperature �C,Heat Temperature �C,Room Temperature �C,Date,Time,1,61,54,87,20,12/3/2016,8:39AM
Wed Dec 28 2016 14:46:19 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)2,41,57,92,21,29/9/2016,3:51PM,3,39,53,89,22,22/12/2016,5:30PM
Wed Dec 28 2016 14:46:29 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)4,56,27,87,23,9/7/2016,6:54AM,5,71,85,76,24,21/10/2016,7:29PM
Wed Dec 28 2016 14:46:39 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)6,82,64,85,25,22/3/2016,9:38PM,7,91,73,94,26,21/10/2016,1:30PM
Wed Dec 28 2016 14:46:49 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)8,35,79,89,27,30/4/2016,2:17PM,9,29,59,83,28,18/7/2016,7:49AM
```

Comment: Hi @Sikorski i was wondering for the output of the interval function, what happen to my machine unit 1,3,5,7. Will they not be added, or it is just that the 'even' number will be shown

Comment: This code works for the output part, however it does not add the data into the collection. It will just print but however add collection/mongodb

Comment: This code works for the output part, however it does not add the data into the collection. It will just print but however does not add to collection/mongodb @Sikorski

Comment: it won't add to mongo because there is no code written for that. I left that integration part for you :)

Comment: check the output carefully, 1 3 5 and 7 are being printed. 1 is in first row, 3 is in 2nd row and so on

Comment: How do i do the integration part may i ask? Do you have guide or answer, as this is for my project and i am new to nodejs as a whole

Answer (score 1):

Sikorski's code is quite good and will work but looks like you're new to node, so I'm gonna break code into components for you, which is not just easier to understand but also a good practice in development.

**For connecting**

```
function connectToMongo() {
  mongoose.connect('mongo_url');
}
```

**For disconnecting**

```
function disconnectToMongo() {
  mongoose.connection.close()
}
```

**For saving data**

```
//Db is name of your mongo collection
Db.create(data, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err); return
  }
});
```

**For reading whole csv**

```
function readDoc() {
  var doc_content = [];
  fs.createReadStream('data.csv').pipe(csv())
               .on('data',function(data){
                  doc_content.push(data)
               })
               .on('end',function(data){
                  console.log('Read finished');
                  return doc_content;
               })
}
```

Now let's use these functions in one function, lets say init which'll run

```
function init() {
  var numOfDocsToSave = 10; //just chnage here for num of docs you want to save in interval
  var interval = 1000 * 10; //10 secs, thanks Sikorski for this 
  var data = readDoc();
  var chunk = [];
  var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    connectToMongo();
    if(data.length >= numOfDocsToSave) {
      chunk = data.splice(0, numOfDocsToSave);
      saveInMongo(chunk);
    } else {
      saveInMongo(data);
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
    disconnectoToMongo(); //we should not open connection for 5 minutes when we're not doing any operation
  }, interval);
  console.log("Interval ended");
}
```

Hope it helps.

**Update**

As you said Db is coming undefined, may be because you haven't created it yet.

So you can do this,

**~model.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testDb');
module.exports = mongoose.model('Db', {
  name: String //change argument with your schema
});
```

**Now import this in your main file**

```
var Db = require('./model'); //assuming your model.js and main file are in same directory
```

Comment: I gotten a error which says Db is not defined. Under 'Saving of data', which i have already changed to my collection, which is meibandb. The error shows 'ReferrenceError: meibandb is not defined'

Comment: @Marcus please see the update and let me know if you still get some error

Answer (score 0):

See if the following code can help you.

```js
var fs= require('fs');
var csv = require('fast-csv');

var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/insertDB';
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var data;

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
    } else {
      console.log('Connection established to', url);
      var collection = db.collection('airports');
      readData=fs.createReadStream('1000data.csv').pipe(csv())
                   .on('data',function(data)
                   {
                      var count = 0; // Count initialised to 0
                      var timeout = setInterval(function() // Insert 10 record after 5 minutes
                      { 
                        if(count >= 999) // If count is 1000 stop inserting.
                        {
                           clearInterval(timeout);
                        }
                        else
                       {
                          for(var i = count; i < count+10; i++)
                          {
                             collection.insert({'data': data[i]}, 
                             function(err)
                             {
                                console.log(err);
                             }); //Insert one record
                          }
                          count += 10; //Increase the count
                        
                         }
                      },300000);
                   })
                   .on('end',function(data){
                      console.log('Read finished');
                   })

    }
  }); //End of Mongo connect
```

**Or you can try following code**

```js
var fs= require('fs');
var csv = require('fast-csv');

var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/insertDB';
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var data;

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
    } else {
      console.log('Connection established to', url);
      var collection = db.collection('airports');
      readData=fs.createReadStream('1000data.csv').pipe(csv())
                   .on('data',function(data)
                   {
                      var count = 0; // Count initialised to 0
                      var timeout = setInterval(function() // Insert 10 record after 5 minutes
                      { 
                        if(count >= 999) // If count is 1000 stop inserting.
                        {
                           clearInterval(timeout);
                        }
                        else
                       {
                          var temp = [];
                          for(var i = count; i < count+10; i++)
                          {
                             temp.push({'data':data[i]});
                          }
                          count += 10; //Increase the count
                          collection.insert(temp, function(err){
                              console.log(err);
                          }); //Insert 10 records at one time.
                         }
                      },300000);
                   })
                   .on('end',function(data){
                      console.log('Read finished');
                   })

    }
  }); //End of Mongo connect
```

The output you will get from your db will be in following format:

```
{data:1,61,54,87,20,12/3/2016,8:39AM},
{data:2,41,57,92,21,29/9/2016,3:51PM},
{data:3,39,53,89,22,22/12/2016,5:30PM},
{data:4,56,27,87,23,9/7/2016,6:54AM},
{data:5,71,85,76,24,21/10/2016,7:29PM},
{data:6,82,64,85,25,22/3/2016,9:38PM},
{data:7,91 ,73,94,26,21/10/2016,1:30PM},
{data:8,35,79,89,27,30/4/2016,2:17PM},
{data:9,29,59,83,28,18/7/2016,7:49AM},
{data:10,19,61,80,29,27/9/2016,8:21PM}
```

Comment: Try the edited code. Let me know if it is throwing any error. Try adding consoles. Please first understand the code before using it. Which will be good for you as you are learning.

Comment: It is not throwing any error, however the data has not been added to the collection. The collections' count have not increase. Also, i was hoping to add 10 data every 5 minute, not all 1000 data at 1 go (which i have already successfully done)

Comment: I asked you to understand the code before proceeding. The code I have added is to push 10 records at one time. Have you tried adding any consoles?

Comment: See the edit. Also let me know what is your db structure. I have posted the db structure you will get after using the code above. If your db structure is different than the given one, you have to modify the code of insertion.